# Just how much power (as a percentage) is necessary to drive a compressor in a jet engine?

Tags: engine, jet, turbofan, efficiency

If i understand correctly this is the "back work ratio". I'd like to know how much % of the "gross" thrust is used by the turbine to drive the compressor in a typical turbofan.

Comment: Since you say turbofan, do you mean just the compressor, or both compressor and fan? Because in turbofan, most power is used to drive the _fan_.

Comment: Just the compressor, since the fan generates useful thrust.